# Ubuntu 18.04 1360x768 resolution available but don't work

Tags: display, 18.04, hdmi, display-resolution

I am using a 32" Insignia TV as a mirrored monitor via HDMI out.

Right now it works great at 1280x720, but if I choose to use 1360x768 the tv goes blank thinking there is nothing plugged in. Any ideas?

NOTE: I am dual booting Windows10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Windows10 works fine in 1360x768.

[image: Screenshot of my display options]

Comment: @PRATAP "Join Displays" does what exactly? The laptop itself sits on a shelf with the lid closed. Join Displays seems to be like making a larger desktop... or Im wrong.

Comment: Ahhh HA! Single Display did it. Now I have even more settings! THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Displays Section.
Select "Single Display" and Select the  32" TV as Primary.
It will give you the options.